# caption package

Tags: captions, subcaption

I am currently preparing a paper for submission using the template files provided by SIAM (see http://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php). I have been writing my document under a different style file with no problems. However, when I come to add in items that rely on the subfigure command, I am presented with an error

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected
                         caption
```

I have read various posts online outlining the issues with the caption package. Therefore, my question is whether or not a reasonable workaround can be sought? I would ideally like to keep using the subcaption package, enabling my figures to be labelled (a), (b), (c), etc, however at present am not in a position to do so as the caption package will not load.

Comment: At this point, the message is just a warning that the full capabilities of the `caption` package might not be available. Do give it a try and check if things look alright and as you would expect them to look. If that's the case, you can ignore the warning message.

Comment: Mico - the issue I have is that this warning leads to six errors, all stemming from an undefined control sequence as a result of caption not being loaded.

Comment: If you're getting outright error messages, it would be helpful if you posted those too. What would be even more helpful is if you posted an MWE (minimum working example: a LaTeX file that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`) that gives rise to the warning message and the error messages you're encountering.